# How to log results of Where method?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm contemplating using a function block predicate in a fluent style Where clause to log some results, for example:

```
var bar = SomeEnumerable.Where(i =>
    {
        if(...)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Log "failure" to in-memory List<T>
            return false;
        }
    }).Select(...);
```

Is there some other way I could capture this that would not introduce side-effect?

I was thinking along the lines of having a Linq extension method that could "tee" its result to more than one subsequent method. Is there already such an operator?

I agree 100% about keeping side-effect away from Linq, if possible.

Comment: I like to keep my LINQ code free of side-effects.

Comment: `Linq` has differed execution, not a good option to log something to file from them...side-effect.

Comment: Eventually, the code will call `ToList()`. I'm not so much interested in "real-time" logging, but some "end of process" log. I agree with "side effect bad". I'm struggling to find a solution that will not have me go through the list multiple times. True about file logging. Should probably consider in-memory list to be written after the process is complete.

Comment: @Servy I answer more questions than I ask on SO. I'd like to understand the reasons for your edits. Was my post "breaking" any rule, or was it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: @LucMorin Your question is where you *ask your question*, not where you include notes on why you made changes to your question.  The revision notes is where you go to actually include information on why you made the edits that you've made.

Comment: @Servy Ok, got it. I've seen tons of questions with those "EDIT" blocks in them, so I assumed it was an accepted practice. Duly noted sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case what you're doing here is not really filtering the sequence, but rather grouping the items into one of two different groups.  There are much better operators for doing this than `Where`.

```
var validatedItems = SomeEnumerable.ToLookup(item => IsValid(item));

foreach(var invalidItem in validatedItems[false])
{
    LogFailure(invalidItem);
}

var bar = validatedItem[true].Select(...);
```

Note that `ToLookup` here eagerly evaluates the source sequence and your validation logic.  If you wanted to defer the validation until later (while also avoiding multiple enumeration of the sequence, which you probably *do* want to do, given that it's doing validation logic) it would greatly complicate this.

Comment: Well, the end result is filtered based on returning `true` or `false` from the code block, but I do like your idea of grouping for "later" processing. It does mean that I have to "interrupt", or "split" the fluent chain, and then resume it with only the desired group. Not a big deal in my specific use-case. I think that using the `GroupBy` operator might allow deferred execution, but my case doesn't require it.

Comment: @LucMorin Using `GroupBy` would either require you to materialize the query into a collection, or iterate it twice, the former is no different than this, the latter is likely unacceptable here, for the reason indicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's your code, do what you want.

If you understand the implication of adding side effects to LINQ, i.e. it won't work with say, a SQL query, and you know it will only be run once `.ToList()` or similar is called.

Go for it!

Logging is a pretty safe side effect in most contexts and if you need the information in your telemetry, that's up to you. I might make it a method and not a lambda, just so readers later on can see clearly the intent.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to get some input about some other possible ways of achieving the same result, but without introducing side-effect.

Comment: Don't think there is any way to do this without just writing the code to do it. You could write an extension method `WhereWithLogging` on `IEnumerable` but that is just moving the issue to a different place. Logging is inherently a side effect, you can make it monadic/transparent https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/ but you're still doing the side effect work.